# Twilio: Can Twilio Studio import a non-Twilio flow definition JSON and create a new flow

Tags: twilio

I have a VUI design as visio diagram and convert that into a JSON. Now I want to import that JSON into Twilio Studio to create a Flow Definition. But Studio accepts only if the JSON is an existing Flow Definition. Is there a way to do this? or create Flow from Visio diagram converted into XML or any other format?

I tried converting the Visio diagram into a JSON using tool and used the Studio Import function to create the flow but that was not accepted by the Studio in the 'Create Flow' wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only import flows that were created with Studio.